# php code to give the position according to their scores (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 3rd, 5th)

Tags: php, sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jss1_prelim` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`term` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`idnumber` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`subject` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`score` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`teacher` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)   ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

INSERT INTO `jss1_prelim` (`id`, `term`, `idnumber`, `subject`, `score`, `teacher`)
VALUES
(1, 'Prelim', 'SBI-JS202', 'Computer', '82', 'TID273'),
(2, 'Prelim', 'SBI-JS645', 'Computer', '63', 'TID273'),
(3, 'Prelim', 'SBI-JS300', 'Computer', '65', 'TID273'),
(4, 'Prelim', 'SBI-JS202', 'Igbo', '70', 'TID015'),
(5, 'Prelim', 'SBI-JS645', 'Igbo', '65', 'TID015');
```

I need help on this script, This script works fine for sorting sql database entries. But I need php code to give the position according to their scores (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 3rd, 5th).

```
<table border = '2'>
<tr>
<td>Student ID</td>
<td>Score</td>
<td>Position</td>
</tr>
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if(!$con)
{
    echo "Could not establish connection to the database " . mysql_error();
}

$mydb = mysql_select_db("sbicenugu", $con);
if (!$mydb)
{
    echo "Error selecting database " . mysql_error();
}

$mystatement = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jss1_prelim ORDER BY score DESC");
$dbcount = mysql_num_rows($mystatement);
$selection = array(0 => "");
$nameselection = array(0 => "");

$i = 0; 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($mystatement))
    {
    $selection[$i] = $row['score'];
    $nameselection[$i] = $row['idnumber'];
    $i++; 
    }
arsort($selection);
ksort($nameselection);

for ($x = 0; $x < $dbcount; $x++)
{
echo "<tr> <td>$nameselection[$x]</td> 
<td>$selection[$x]</td>
<td>"; $grades = array($selection[$x]);
$occurrences = array_count_values($grades);
$grades = array_unique($grades);
foreach($grades as $grade) 
{
if($grade == end($grades))$i += $occurrences[$grade]-1;
echo str_repeat('-'.($i + 1).'<br>',$occurrences[$grade]);
$i+= $occurrences[$grade];
}
echo"</td> 
</tr>"; 
}
?>
</table>
```

This scripts was not giving me what i expected for the position of the student in class. also it gives different value position for those that their score are desame.
I need help for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This SQL code will give you the rank as column "rank" and works well with partial results, so you always have the right rank even when showing the second page of multiple pages:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
    FROM jss1_prelim ref
    WHERE ref.score > main.score) as rank,
    id, term, idnumber, subject, score, teacher
FROM jss1_prelim main
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Make sure to put an index on `score` for better performance.

Comment: i just add the script... how can i echo it on the position <TD>

Comment: the result of the subquery is aliased with `as rank`, so you can access it with `$row['rank']` in your code

Comment: it works but echo all student scores as 4th position ( no 1st or 2rd base on their score performance)

Comment: Then you did something different. [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/991a5/5)

Comment: why a student score **100** is not position as 1st but **99** and others works

Comment: Oh, I did not notice that your score column is `VARCHAR`, so there will be lexical comparison character by character. Is there a reason you did not use `INT`?

Comment: likewise i didn't think of it to be the prob... its cool now, i have change it to `INT`

Comment: i just uploaded another question `php error on student total score position` . i respect your contributions