# Php + MySQL scoreboard

Tags: php, mysql

I have managed to make a scoreboard which works completely fine, but there is a small problem with it. I am always increasing my "place" number by 1. If two competitors have the same results they should have the same "place".

My code at the moment(only PHP I am echoing it in a table):

```
<?php

          while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $u10z ) ){

            print "<tr>";

            print "<td>" . $i1 . "</td>";           

            print "<td>" . $row['ime'] . "</td>"; 

            print "<td>" . $row['priimek'] . "</td>"; 

            print "<td>" . $row['klub'] . "</td>";

            print "<td>" . $row['drzava'] . "</td>";

            print "<td>" . $row['vrh'] . "</td>";

            print "<td>" . $row['vrhPoskus'] . "</td>";

            print "<td>" . $row['bonus'] . "</td>";

            print "<td>" . $row['bonusPoskus'] . "</td>";

            print "</tr>";

            $i1++;

          }

        ?>
```

As you can see the `$i1` is a "place" counter.

Example:
[example image of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZmpO.png)

If you look at he second table, the `first(1)` and the `second(2)` competitor should both be on `first(1)` place as they both have the same score.

Also the `eighth(8)` and `ninth(9)` competitor should both be on `eighth(8)` place.

**EDIT:**

I am now using the code, which was commented below, but i have a little problem. The numbers are shifted.

```
<?php

    $pre_vrh = false;
    $pre_vrhPoskus = false;
    $pre_bonus = false;
    $pre_bonusPoskus = false;
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $u10z ) ){
        print "<tr>";
        print "<td>" . $i1 . "</td>";           
        print "<td>" . $row['ime'] . "</td>"; 
        print "<td>" . $row['priimek'] . "</td>"; 
        print "<td>" . $row['klub'] . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . $row['drzava'] . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . $row['vrh'] . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . $row['vrhPoskus'] . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . $row['bonus'] . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . $row['bonusPoskus'] . "</td>";
        print "</tr>";

        if ($pre_vrh != $row['vrh'] || $pre_vrhPoskus != $row['vrhPoskus'] || $pre_bonus != $row['bonus'] || $pre_bonusPoskus != $row['bonusPoskus']) {
            $i1++;
        }
        $pre_vrh = $row['vrh'];
        $pre_vrhPoskus = $row['vrhPoskus'];
        $pre_bonus = $row['bonus'];
        $pre_bonusPoskus = $row['bonusPoskus'];
      }

   ?>
```

Image:
[New results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZmpO.png)

Comment: Take a look at this thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324830/php-code-to-give-the-position-according-to-their-scores-1st-2nd-3rd-3rd-5th, seems to be what you are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand what you means when talking about score, but ... it looks like if `$row['vrh'], $row['vrhPoskus'], $row['bonus'], $row['bonusPoskus']` are the same then place must be the same. If it's true when code can be like this

```
<?php

    $pre_vrh = false;
    $pre_vrhPoskus = false;
    $pre_bonus = false;
    $pre_bonusPoskus = false;
    $place = 1;
    $i1 = 0;
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $u10z ) ){
        print "<tr>";

        // we should compare old and new values for getting place
        if ($pre_vrh != $row['vrh'] || $pre_vrhPoskus != $row['vrhPoskus'] || $pre_bonus != $row['bonus'] || $pre_bonusPoskus != $row['bonusPoskus']) {
            $place = $i1 + 1;
        }
        $i1++;

        print "<td>" . $place . "</td>";           
        print "<td>" . $row['ime'] . "</td>"; 
        print "<td>" . $row['priimek'] . "</td>"; 
        print "<td>" . $row['klub'] . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . $row['drzava'] . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . $row['vrh'] . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . $row['vrhPoskus'] . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . $row['bonus'] . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . $row['bonusPoskus'] . "</td>";
        print "</tr>";


        $pre_vrh = $row['vrh'];
        $pre_vrhPoskus = $row['vrhPoskus'];
        $pre_bonus = $row['bonus'];
        $pre_bonusPoskus = $row['bonusPoskus'];
    }    
?>
```

Comment: Thanks it kinda works, but the places are shifted. Picure [link](http://i.imgur.com/7o00bmK.png?1) @alexander.polomodov

Comment: Can you explain about shifted places? Maybe you need places 1, 2, 2, 4, 5 ...?

Comment: Sorry. As the score is the same with first and second competitor (4,4,4,4) they both should be on the first place. The next competitor with score (2,3,4,5) is on the third place. And so on as we come to the last two competitors who have same score again (0,0,0,0) and they should have the same "place" - (eighth). @alexander.polomodov

Comment: I modify answer and move if condition to the top for getting place, can you check this code?

Comment: Seems like everything works. Great! @alexander.polomodov